# change class style of parent element in specific div media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my .container element to be at a width of 100% when it reaches a screen size of 900px. The problem is that I use .container on every page and only want to affect the appearance of .container in the #sub-top div.

the hardest thing is terminology for me but i think this is the closest to what i have the ability to describe.

As you can see below, i am trying to get the .container class to go to 100% rather than 85% when it reaches a screen size of 900px or smaller.

```css
@media
.container{
 width: 85%;
 height: auto;
}
#sub-top{
 background-color: gray;
 height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
#sub-top .container {
 width: 100% !important;
 height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sub-top">
   <div class="container">
  <div class ="content"> 
      <p> HERE IS CONTENT </p>
  </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
  .container {
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

#sub-top {
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #sub-top .container {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #sub-top .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the **!important** is needed or wanted.

Comment: You're right, I just copied and pasted his code. Will edit now.